# Regular Expression Integrity Constraints in SQLite3

Tags: sqlite, regular-expression

In a SQLite3 CREATE TABLE statement, can I use a regular expression to enforce a particular constraint? Specifically, I am trying to require that an inputted URL is valid. I know there are other ways of doing this besides using regular expressions, but because of the structure of my project, this is the method I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP` with a `CHECK()` constraint.

First, I would run a check on the column that you want to validate to ensure it will pass the constraint:

```
select * from staff where emp_ref not regexp '[A]?[0-9]{6}';
```

This should output any records that won't pass your proposed constraint (*check* in SQLite terminology). This is useful as it will highlight any potential issues with your data and/or your regex.

Unfortunately, due to a limitation in the architecture of SQLite, you can't add a check to a previously created column. To enable a check on a row of a previously created table, you have to create a new column with a different name:

```
alter table staff
add column employee_ref char(10)
check(employee_ref regexp '[A]?[0-9]{6}');
```

You can then delete the old column:

```
alter table staff drop column <colname>;
```